# ElasticSearch Views integration not working with multiple words

Tags: views, 9

In Drupal 9 I have setup ElasticSearch 7. I have added a Search API View in which I have added field to search through the "rendered HTML" field.

This seems all pretty basic if you ask me, however it doesn't work as expected.

For example my page contains text like "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet".

- If I search for "ipsum" I get the page as a result
- If I search for "dolor" I get the same result
- But if I search for "ipsum dolor" I get no results at all

Do I miss configuration in either my view, or my ElasticSearch index, or is this some weird missing feature in the views integration.
I believe I know enough of both to say that I haven't missed a checkbox or processor, but who knows.

I also haven't found any issues other than [this one](https://www.drupal.org/project/elasticsearch_connector/issues/2951165), which is open for 3 years already. If this is an actual bug I would expect more activity on it, so I expect that I am missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I simply used the wrong type of filter.

When looking for filter options in the view I typed "search" and the first result was "Combine fields filter - Combine multiple fields together and search by them.", so I used that without looking further.

Instead I had to use "Fulltext search - Search several or all fulltext fields at once."